# css navigation bar position fixed not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website. I decided to make the navigation bar have a fixed position so when I scroll down I can always see it but, when I add to the nav element the property position:fixed it just disappears. Cant' figure out what's happening. Can someone explain, what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much!
*P.S: I am new to coding.*

HTML and CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header nav #logo {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #242628;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

nav ul li {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(12, 240, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rate it!</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers and your time. After I set top, left and right properties to 0 everything works ok. It seems that I had another element with a z-index specified that was messing up everything. I changed the z-index value for the nav element and now, everything works just fine.

Comment: setting `left` and `right` to 0 is an alternative to having `width: 100%` (as I wrote inmy answer) but both methods have the effect of defining a width for the fixed element.  `left: 0` alone won't work, BTW...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fix the position you have to specify where you want it.

top: 20px;
left: 0px;

Etc....

Comment: not really - you'd also need `right: 0` for this to work - as an alternative method to having width: `100%`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `width` to fixed elements (100% in this case):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header nav #logo {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #242628;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

nav ul li {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(12, 240, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rate it!</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `nav` is set to `realtive` and is changed to `fixed` your `absolute` elements will be relative to the `body` and those elements will leave the `nav`.

Change the `position` of the `absolute` elements and the css of the `nav` to:

```
nav {
    background-color: #242628;
    height: 70px;
    padding-left: 20px; }
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I let you here a working version. I only replaced `relative` with `fixed` in your code to the `nav`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
}

header nav #logo {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #242628;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

nav ul li {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(12, 240, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rate it!</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Note that I set `height` to 300% to have some scroll on the document

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see anything wrong:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWpLdd

```
.scrollTest {
  height: 2000px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
}
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0; }

html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%; }

header nav #logo {
     width: 140px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 15px; }

nav {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #242628;
     height: 70px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 800px;
     padding-left: 200px; }

nav ul li {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid gray; }

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(12, 240, 255, 0.3); }

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px; }
```

Make sure you're adding it to the nav parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header nav #logo {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #242628;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
   width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 
}

nav ul li {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(12, 240, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

article{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img id="logo" src="" alt="logo" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rate it!</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<article></article>
```

Working code